# OFDM spectrum, HACKRF, and GNUradio companion

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

I am trying to analyze the spectrum of wifi spectrum.

I getting a good OFDM spectrum with my HackRF at 2.412 GHz (from my first QTGUI Sink).

[image]

But I get nothing out of OFDM Receiver. I was wondering why.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Comment in 2022: This is a really really old version of GNU Radio (3.7); it's so old that I can't even compile it on my system to reproduce your problem (and I used to head the GNU Radio project for 3 years, so I don't think that's a competence issue on my end). It's time to update your GNU Radio, so you get the bug-fixed, modern version of all the things. It's honestly gotten a lot easier to install on any operating system these days!